# Sorting dynamic elements in isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm building a list of ships, using jQuery's $.each loop and a JSON file created in Google Sheets (Tabletop.js), and trying to sort them with Isotope.js.

jQuery creates the list without any issues. However, when I click on my button to sort the elements via Isotope, nothing happens.

When I hardcode the elements into my HTML page, Isotope sorts everything no problem.

I've looked all over the Internet and couldn't find an answer.

The loop with a callback to another function that fetches my data from a spreadsheet. `#port` is a div in my HTML where everything is going.

Here's the code I'm working with.

```
function showInfo(data, tabletop) {

    var shipData = tabletop.sheets('data').all();

    var items=[];

    $.each(shipData, function(i) {

        //Put each ship in the port ^__-
        var ship = "<div class=\"ship\"><div class=\"row\"><p class=\"name font-lg\">" + shipData[i].name + "</p><p class=\"cruise-line font-xs\">" + shipData[i].line +"</p><div class=\"ship-photo col-md-9 col-sm-9\"><img src=\"img/" + shipData[i].img + "\" class=\"img-responsive\"></div><div class=\"ship-info col-md-3 col-sm-3\"><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"header font-xs col-sm-4 col-xs-4\">Launched</div><div class=\"header font-xs col-sm-4 col-xs-4\">Length</div><div class=\"header font-xs col-sm-4 col-xs-4\">Tonnage</div></div><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"year font-lg col-sm-4 col-xs-4\">" + shipData[i].launchYear +"</div><div class=\"length font-lg col-sm-4 col-xs-4\">" + shipData[i].length + "'</div><div class=\"weight font-lg col-sm-4 col-xs-4\">" + shipData[i].tonnage + "</div></div></div><div class=\"ship-info col-md-3 col-sm-3\"><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"header font-xs col-sm-6 col-xs-6\">Max capacity</div><div class=\"header font-xs col-sm-6 col-xs-6\">Crew</div></div><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"max-passenger font-lg col-sm-6 col-xs-6\">" + shipData[i].maxCapacity + "</div><div class=\"crew font-lg col-sm-6 col-xs-6\">" + shipData[i].crewCapacity + "</div></div></div></div>";

            items.push(ship);

      });

    $port.append(items)
}
```

Here's my Isotope sorting code:

```
// init Isotope
    $('#port').isotope({
        itemSelector: ".ship",
        layoutMode: 'vertical',
        getSortData: {
            name: '.ship'
        }
    })

// bind sort button click
$('#sorts').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var sortValue = $this.attr('data-sort-value');

     $('#port').isotope({ 
            sortBy: sortValue 
     });

  });
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="compare">
    <h3>How the ships compare</h3>
    <div id="sorts" class="button-group">
                <button class="button" data-sort-value="name">name</button>
                <button class="button" data-sort-value="length">length</button>
                <button class="button" data-sort-value="weight">weight</button>
                <button class="button" data-sort-value="passengers">passenger</button>
                <button class="button" data-sort-value="original-order">clear</button>      
            </div>
        </div>

<div id="port"></div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jn690d63/). One list is generated in JS while the other is made in HTML.

Comment: You should add a jsfiddle to this, will make you chances of quick answer go up drastically! www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I've updated my question with a JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues to fix.

Change #sorts to this:

```
<button id="sort"  data-sort-value="name">Click to sort</button>
```

and your data function to this:

```
$.each(data, function (i) {
$('.port').append("<li><div class='name'>" + data[i] + "</div></li>");
});
```

Comment: For sort to work you needed to have a data-sort-value for the button since you called it in your click function. You also had the li element with the class name when there needed to be a div within the li with that class. Glad it worked. If it is correct, please mark it answered.